# Adding a newline into a string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string.

```
string strToProcess = "fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@dfsdfjk72388389@kdkfkdfkkl@jkdjkfjd@jjjk@";
```

I need to add a newline after every occurence of "@" symbol in the string.

My Output should be like this

```
fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@
dfsdfjk72388389@
kdkfkdfkkl@
jkdjkfjd@
jjjk@
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the newline is not effective in the text file"? How are you writing to the text file?

Comment: Post the code you use to write the file out. \r\n (windows - Environment.Newline) or \n (Unix) should work...

Answer (score 606, accepted):

Use `Environment.NewLine` whenever you want in any string. An example:

```
string text = "fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@dfsdfjk72388389@kdkfkdfkkl@jkdjkfjd@jjjk@";

text = text.Replace("@", "@" + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: But I need to write this information in a text file like this fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@ dfsdfjk72388389@ kdkfkdfkkl@ jkdjkfjd@ jjjk@ The New line character is not effective in the text file.

Comment: This is not a good solution, since System.String (alias `string`) is an immutable object, which means that the entire string is being copied over. Better to use a System.Text.StringBuilder object for operations such as String.Replace.

Comment: @Alexander I'd say that string operations being inefficient is a problem we don't have to worry anymore in 2019.

Comment: @FilipeMadureira that is so wrong in so many ways. Hardware improvements or not, there is never an excuse for being a bad programmer on purpose. If we know how to do it better we should. Besides imagine implementing this in a library which is being used in a core feature in a database system - you would want high performance.

Comment: @Alexander Being a good programmer is a luxury only people who haven't deadlines / bad jobs/bosses can have, otherwise, I'd agree with you. I thought my point was clear at first.

Answer (score 82):

You can add a new line character after the @ symbol like so:

```
string newString = oldString.Replace("@", "@\n");
```

You can also use the `NewLine` property in the `Environment` Class (I think it is Environment).

Comment: But I need to write this information in a text file like this

fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@ dfsdfjk72388389@ kdkfkdfkkl@ jkdjkfjd@ jjjk@

The New line character is not effective in the text file.

Answer (score 21):

The previous answers come close, but to meet the actual requirement that the `@` symbol stay close, you'd want that to be `str.Replace("@", "@" + System.Environment.NewLine)`.  That will keep the `@` symbol and add the appropriate newline character(s) for the current platform.

Answer (score 13):

Then just modify the previous answers to:

```
Console.Write(strToProcess.Replace("@", "@" + Environment.NewLine));
```

If you don't want the newlines in the text file, then don't preserve it.

Answer (score 8):

A simple string replace will do the job.  Take a look at the example program below:

```
using System;

namespace NewLineThingy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@dfsdfjk72388389@kdkfkdfkkl@jkdjkfjd@jjjk@";
            str = str.Replace("@", "@" + Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

as others have said new line char will give you a new line in a text file in windows.
try the following:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WriteToFile
        (
        @"C:\test.txt",
        "fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@dfsdfjk72388389@kdkfkdfkkl@jkdjkfjd@jjjk@",
        "@"
        );

        /*
        output in test.txt in windows =
        fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@
        dfsdfjk72388389@
        kdkfkdfkkl@
        jkdjkfjd@
        jjjk@ 
        */
    }

    public static void WriteToFile(string filename, string text, string newLineDelim)
    {
        bool equal = Environment.NewLine == "\r\n";

        //Environment.NewLine == \r\n = True
        Console.WriteLine("Environment.NewLine == \\r\\n = {0}", equal);

        //replace newLineDelim with newLineDelim + a new line
        //trim to get rid of any new lines chars at the end of the file
        string filetext = text.Replace(newLineDelim, newLineDelim + Environment.NewLine).Trim();

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(filename)))
        {
            sw.Write(filetext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only saw your environment.newline == \r\n = true now (maybe I missed it because it is not C# syntax ;) ). Also, more info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.newline.aspx. Just stumbled upon a similar problem with using hardcoded \n not giving me a new line in windows..

Answer (score 5):

```
string strToProcess = "fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@dfsdfjk72388389@kdkfkdfkkl@jkdjkfjd@jjjk@";
var result = strToProcess.Replace("@", "@ \r\n");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAIFU.png)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 4):

```
string str = "fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@dfsdfjk72388389@kdkfkdfkkl@jkdjkfjd@jjjk@";
str = str.Replace("@", Environment.NewLine);
richTextBox1.Text = str;
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your string as mentioned below.

```
string strToProcess = "fkdfdsfdflkdkfk"+ System.Environment.NewLine +" dfsdfjk72388389"+ System.Environment.NewLine +"kdkfkdfkkl"+ System.Environment.NewLine +"jkdjkfjd"+ System.Environment.NewLine +"jjjk"+ System.Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your replies to everyone else, something like this is what you're looking for.

```
string file = @"C:\file.txt";
string strToProcess = "fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@dfsdfjk72388389@kdkfkdfkkl@jkdjkfjd@jjjk@";
string[] lines = strToProcess.Split(new char[] { '@' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(line + "@");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `string[] something = text.Split('@')`. Make sure you use single quotes to surround the "@" to store it as a `char` type.
This will store the characters up to and including each "@" as individual words in the array. You can then output each (`element + System.Environment.NewLine`) using a for loop or write it to a text file using `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines([file path + name and extension], [array name])`. If the specified file doesn't exist in that location it will be automatically created.

Answer (score -2):

In the provided below code, you have a server-side event handler for a button click (Button1_Click). It appears that you want to insert line breaks (
) after each occurrence of the "@" symbol in the string and then write the modified string to the HTTP response.

Your approach to achieve this by using the Replace method to insert 
 after each "@" symbol is correct. Here's the modified code with comments:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         string str = "fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@dfsdfjk72388389@kdkfkdfkkl@jkdjkfjd@jjjk@";
         str = str.Replace("@", "@" + "<br/>");
         Response.Write(str);       
     }
```

This code will produce the following output:

```
fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@<br/>dfsdfjk72388389@<br/>kdkfkdfkkl@<br/>jkdjkfjd@<br/>jjjk@<br/>
```

Each "@" symbol in the original string is followed by a line break (
) in the output. If you are rendering this HTML on a web page, the line breaks will be displayed as expected. However, if you are using this in a context where HTML rendering is not allowed or you want to render it as plain text, you might want to replace 
 with actual newline characters (\n) instead.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Thank you for answering the question. However it is good practice to add some explanation as to why this works.

Answer (score -2):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
             string strToProcess = "fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@dfsdfjk72388389@kdkfkdfkkl@jkdjkfjd@jjjk@";
            strToProcess.Replace("@", Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine(strToProcess);
    }
}
```