# Add new line in a foreach loop, which is being added to a table cell in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, newline

This is a bit of an odd question, and I'm sure there was an easier way of doing this but...

I have a method that returns a **List** of names. I am parsing through this list with a **foreach** loop. I am adding each name to one long **String** so that I can set the text of a **Table Cell** to that string. But I can't seem to get it to add a **new line**. Is this possible?

Here's a snippet of the code:

*Earlier my table loop:*

```
TableCell tempCell = new TableCell();
```

*The issue:*

```
// Returns a List of Employees on the specified day and time.
List<string> EmployeeList = CheckForEmployees(currentDay, timeCount);

string PrintedList = "";
foreach (String s in EmployeeList)
{
    PrintedList += s;
    // PrintedList += s + System.Environment.NewLine;
    // PrintedList += s + " \n";
}
tempCell.Text = PrintedList;
```

Both the commented code lines didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a newline into a string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224236/adding-a-newline-into-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I came here right after I saw that thread. Both of the suggestions didn't work.

Comment: I would recommend using stringbuilder. Also, you can try using <br /> tag.

Comment: I just rewrote the code with a StringBuilder. I'll use that from now on, it's much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append a break tag since you want the new line to show in HTML. So append `<br/>`. I would also recommend using a stringbuilder if it is more than a few iterations.

Comment: I feel silly for not even trying that. This line of code worked:

PrintedList += s + "<br />"

Comment: Glad it helped. Thanks to safetyOtter for editing my answer. (Or maybe I was just showing how a break tag worked) :)

Answer (score 1):

Table cell as in HTML table cell? Do you perhaps need to use the "br" tag instead of normal newline?

Another thing, you should use StringBuilder instead of doing string concatenation the way you do. Or even better, [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string PrintedList = String.Join("br-tag", EmployeeList);
```

Again, not sure if the br-tag is what you are after, but prefer to use the methods in the String class when possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It was the <br /> tag that I needed. Attila answered 5 minutes before you, so I gave him the check, but I had no idea String.Join was a thing, very useful!