# C# string replace "," with a linebreak (Enter)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a text string with many ",".
I would like to replace all "," with an Enter or a linebreak.
How can achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: quick search brought this up, I think it's what your looking for
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224236/adding-a-newline-into-a-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Note: Environment.NewLine is not *always* 'correct'. (Just because it comes up more of then naught; and generally without a disclaimer.)

Comment: For the record, I voted to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224236/adding-a-newline-into-a-string-in-c-sharp), not as too broad; Stack Overflow's closing mechanism is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourString = yourString.Replace(",", System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Demo here https://dotnetfiddle.net/M2lBKS

Answer (score 1):

There is an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) that talks about the Replace method for strings. Here is an example.

```
string s = stringwithcomma.Replace(",", System.Environment.NewLine);
```