# How can I add line break tag before for txtmessage.Text?

Tags: html, email, c#-4.0, line-breaks

```
mail.Body = "your appointment has been scheduled on :" + txtappointment.Text + " " + txtmessage.Text;
```

Comment: Do you want a line break ( <br />) or a new line?

Comment: linebreak brother

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mail.Body ="your appointment has been scheduled on :"+ <br> + txtappointment.Text +" "+ txtmessage.Text;
```

Comment: i want  add break tag before "txtmessage.text";

Comment: iam expecting output is ::your appointment has been scheduled on 29-9-2016 next line morning 10:00am

Answer (score 0):

For a new line you should use `\n`. Or have a look at this older post : 
[Adding a newline into a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224236/adding-a-newline-into-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this `+Environment.NewLine+`

```
mail.Body ="your appointment has been scheduled on :"+ <br> + txtappointment.Text +System.Environment.NewLine+ txtmessage.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is Example With Solution Of Your Question,Try It Once ,Your Answer In Comment In My Snippet .**

```js
//mail.Body ="your appointment has been scheduled on :"+ txtappointment.Text +"\n"+ txtmessage.Text;
var Fname = "samudrala";
var Lname = "Raamu";
alert(Fname+"\n"+Lname);
```

Comment: correct code is::mail.Body ="your appointment has been scheduled on :"+ txtappointment.Text +"\n"+ txtmessage.Text;

Comment: send u r mail brother...any doubt iam asking u

Comment: Also use mail.Body ="your appointment has been scheduled on :"+ txtappointment.Text +'<br>'+ txtmessage.Text; this is Dynamically addibg one html tag that's breaking lines but the pure javascript its not correct we can user "\n" is correct

Comment: samudrala.ramu145@gmail.com

Comment: how to add textcolor bro

Comment: var s="samudrala"; s.fontcolor("Your color here");

Answer (score 0):

According your comments you need something like this (and you should use the [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method for easy string managing:

```
mail.Body = string.format("your appointment has been scheduled on: {0}<br/>{1}", txtappointment.Text, txtmessage.Text);
```

You can see the placeholders for your text editor's text, first one is for appointment, second one is for message. For the html to work, you must set the `IsBodyHtml` flag for this:

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

If your email client doesn't support the html or you don't want it to be html, use the [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) constant, as @AsifuzzamanRedoy suggested, like this:

```
mail.Body = string.format("your appointment has been scheduled on: {0}{2}{1}", txtappointment.Text, txtmessage.Text, Environment.NewLine);
```