# How to make newline work with a plain C# string?

Tags: c#

I am very very new to Csharp. I am editing a file parsing application a coworker wrote before he left. I am trying to send an HTML formatted email that's supposed to alert users when the app runs into an exception:

```
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex.Message);  //63-116

        string fromemail = "sampleem@samp.com";
        string toemail = "sampleem@samp.com";
        string subject = "Automated From Repair Cruncher";
        string team = "Data Engineering Team";
        string body = "The following error occured in Client.Handler.EntityHandler.cs while Parser was processing:\n";
        body += ex.Message;
        var result = EmailUtil.Emailalert(fromemail, toemail, subject, team, body);
    }
```

However, when I get the email, there is no newline between the processing and the ex.message. It does it on the same line. Why is this? I also tried \n but it didn't give me newline either

I have tried Environment.Newline but it doesn't work either

Comment: Are you sure it's actually missing? `\n` should work just fine, I wonder if your email client is trying to render it as HTML or rich text and ignoring the newline.

Comment: @superstator Yes it is actually trying to send an HTML email. The string is fed into an HTML string that displays it as an HTML email. I did try to use Environement.Newline and it is not working. I assume it's the HTML causing the issue? If so, what is a remedy?

Comment: Insert HTML formatting, like `<br>` or `<p>`

Comment: I would suggest using `ex.ToString()` instead of `ex.Message` since the most valuable part is often the stack trace, and not just the message.

Comment: @John so ex.ToString() gives you a more verbose alert? I will test it. Never seen this before either. I just got thrown into this as an intern with very little .net knowledge

Comment: @superstator Thanks that worked. I had similar code in python and I never needed to do that. I wonder why in C# I need to use an HTML tag to create the space. Python just did it with '\n'

Comment: I would go with @superstator, HTML doesn't care about `\n`, in face if you create an html document and just write hello on two different lines they will apear inline. Use <br>.

Comment: It has nothing to do with C#, it's being formatted through HTML

Comment: `Python just did it with '\n'` If that is true (which is hard to verify since you haven't provided code) then Python is likely converting `\n` to `<br />`.

Comment: Yes, or your Python app was outputting plain text email instead of html

Comment: @mjwills I will check back in with Python code just to make sure I am not talking out of my butt. But yes, I used the Python logic which is why I never bothered with <br/>. The python logic would print things exactly as I formatted the string in Python with no HTML tags. The HTML tags only came into play with making tables. Not pure strings. Interesting to see the difference. I have A LOT to learn about .net

Comment: Again - this is likely not a C# vs Python issue. You are sending a HTML email. So if you need a line break you need to generate a line break _in HTML_.

Answer (score -5):

string text = "fkdfdsfdflkdkfk@dfsdfjk72388389@kdkfkdfkkl@jkdjkfjd@jjjk@";

text = text.Replace("@", "@" + System.Environment.NewLine);

[Adding a newline into a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224236/adding-a-newline-into-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Please refer this link. Thanks.